# Python - why '&' and 'and' operators provide different results though evaluate the condition with same result

Tags: python

I have just started learning Python. I have come across the below problem. As shown below, I am writing a same statement once using '&' operator and then using 'and' operator. Though both of these operators evaluate the 'if' condition to the same Boolean output,**'True'** (***True 'and' True is True*** and also ***True & True is True***), why are the results different? Why is '&' giving wrong answer? Appreciate any clarifications.

```
a = 70
b = 40
c = 60

x = a if a>b and a>c else b if b>c else c
print('Max value with "and":', x)

x = a if a>b & a>c else b if b>c else c
print('Max value with "ampersand":', x)
```

The output is:

Max value with "and": 70

Max value with "ampersand": 60

Comment: `&` is for bitwise operations. If you want the boolean `and`, use `and`.

Answer (score 3):

> why are the results different? Why is '&' giving wrong answer?

Because they're completely different operators with completely different semantics *and completely different [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=precedence#operator-precedence)*: `&` applies before `>` which applies before `and`.

So when you write `a > b and a > c` it's parsed as `(a > b) and (a > c)`.

But when you write `a > b & a > c`, it's parsed as `a > (b & a) > c`.

There's an other difference which is not relevant here but would be a factor in other context: `and` (and `or`) are *lazy* operators, meaning they will evaluate their left operands, then do their thing, and only then evaluate the second operand. `&` however is a normal "eager" operator, it evaluates both operands and only then applies whatever it does.

Finally, and this is of course the biggest difference: `and` works on everything and is non-overridable; `&` only works on types which specifically support it, and does whatever it was defined as (for integers it's a bitwise AND, but for sets it's intersection).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thorough explanation. However, wonder why it is made such complicated in Python which seems to be a very easy language otherwise. It would be great if simplified by getting rid of one of them.

Comment: It's not complicated, and they fulfil completely different use cases. Those use cases just happen to yield similar results when applied specifically to `bool`. That does not make them interchangeable.